# R Turning several functions to one object using Object Oriented Programming (S3 and S4)

Tags: r, r-s3, r-s4

I'm trying to understand how to turn functions into object oriented programming in R. So for example, how could the data and 2 functions below be turned into one object using S3 (and then S4)?
(Perhaps some other simple data and functions would serve better as examples?)

```
data <- c(1, 2, 3)

# Function 1
adding_1 <- function(x){
  x <- x+1
}

# Function 2
subtracting_1 <- function(x){
  x <- x-1
}
```

And how would below functions be executed using the OOP.

```
data1 <- adding_1(data)
data1
data2 <- subtracting_1(data)
data2
```

Comment: What do you mean by "object oriented programming"?  There are lots of different styles of that.  S3 and S4 use a very different style from Java or C++.  The R6 package is somewhat more similar to them.

Comment: I would like to see an example using S3 please. I think that this would help me understand OOP better.

Comment: I would suggest going through the OO section of Hadley Wickham's "Advanced R". https://adv-r.hadley.nz/oo.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R, object-oriented programming is implemented in several very different ways.
The S3 type of OO is the most used because it's very simple and yet does a good job at having what seems to be the same functions behave differently with different types of objects. A good reference is [Advanced R by Hadley Wickham](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html).

In R objects have `attributes`. One of these attributes is the special `class` attribute. You can see this with

```
x <- 1:3
y <- c(1, 2, 3)
class(x)    # "integer"
class(y)    # "numeric"
```

The S3 system is a function overloading system. A special function is defined, the **generic**. Then other functions, the **methods**, are defined to process objects depending or their classes. A method that must be defined is the **default method**.

Here I use your example to define first a generic and then the default method.

```
# Function 1
adding_1 <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("adding_1")
adding_1.default <- function(x, ...){
  x <- x + 1
  x
}
```

Now the methods for objects of class `"list"` and `"data.frame"`.

```
adding_1.list <- function(x, ...){
  num <- sapply(x, is.numeric)
  x[num] <- lapply(x[num], adding_1)
  x
}
adding_1.data.frame <- function(x, ...){
  num <- sapply(x, is.numeric)
  x[num] <- lapply(x[num], adding_1)
  x
}
```

And the same for `subtracting_1`.

```
# Function 2
subtracting_1 <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("subtracting_1")
subtracting_1.default <- function(x){
  x <- x - 1
  x
}
subtracting_1.list <- function(x, ...){
  num <- sapply(x, is.numeric)
  x[num] <- lapply(x[num], subtracting_1)
  x
}
subtracting_1.data.frame <- function(x, ...){
  num <- sapply(x, is.numeric)
  x[num] <- lapply(x[num], subtracting_1)
  x
}
```

**Test cases.**

When called with `x` as an argument (or `y` above) it's the default method that is called since there is no `adding_1.integer` nor `adding_1.numeric`.

And the same goes for `mat`.

But when called with a data frame, a special processing is needed in order not to have the function try to add `1` to character strings or other types of non-numeric column vectors that might be in the data frame.

```
mat <- matrix(1:6, 3)
df1 <- data.frame(x = letters[1:5], y = rnorm(5), z = 101:105)

adding_1(x)
adding_1(mat)
adding_1(df1)

subtracting_1(x)
subtracting_1(mat)
subtracting_1(df1)
```

Comment: Please note that when I run subtracting_1(df1); I get Warning: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: @Gorp Yes, you are right, there were 2 bugs in `subtracting_1`: 1) the string in `UseMethod` had a typo, the first `t` was missing; 2) what should be `subtracting_1.default` was missing the `default` part and therefore the generic was no longer a generic, another object of the same name had been created.